# VBA run infinitely in this web scrape code. How to set it to wait until finish first part?

Tags: excel, vba, connection, infinite-loop, scrape

Here is part of the code, where I believe problem is...

```
URL = "http://www.radiowavemonitor.com/Subscriber/fi_stations_r100.asp?ID=" & JAZZLINK & "&IDF=7"

Set QT = WS.QueryTables.Add( _
    Connection:="URL;" & URL, _
    Destination:=WS.Range("A1"))

With QT
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
    .Name = "LINK"
    .FieldNames = True
    .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

When I try line by line with F8 everything is fine and dandy, but when I run entire code it just start to run infinitely (I let it run for 2,3 hours than break it - and no, it doesnt show me where it breaks as I have to force close it!). I think it have problem when it refresh query and it doesnt wait for connection to load and continue performing rest of code and it is what make him go to infinite loop (when I run line by line, everything is OK). So, unless something else is problem, I would like to know how to set query to wait on page to load entirely (Im not too good at this), also, how to set some error checking on link if it is broken or empty to skip on next?

Comment: use macro recorder to record a new query

Comment: what do you get when you navigate to the URL using a web browser? .... how big is the table? .... you included only a part of your code.... do you have any loops in the rest of the code? ..... put `stop` command before `.refresh` and run the code. does it still hang someplace? or does it get all the way to `stop`?

Comment: Run all the way. Rest shouldnt be a problem too, I have just some plain copy/paste and going to next link in a row in a loop. It helped with some links with DoEvents (I just tried), but what if link is broken or have error on page(noticed on one)? How to make to skip those?

Comment: And here is the ERROR i get when run on some issues by following some links: ADODB.Field error '80020009'